# Cannot resolve symbol ReactComponent in WebStorm

Tags: javascript, reactjs, ecmascript-6, webstorm

I am importing SVG images as components in React. WebStorm highlights a warning `cannot resolve symbol ReactComponent`.

Is there any way to fix it without disabling the warning?

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What IDE build do you use? Similar issue ([WEB-40094](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/WEB-40094)) is fixed in the most recent WebStorm update